# flush the boot journal log after every line

Tags: linux, boot

My old hp laptop (Celeron N3060) won't boot with a 6.1.* kernel. The 6.0.18 kernel still boots fine. The boot log (`journalctl -b-1`) for a failed boot ends after about a 1000 lines with

> Jan 27 17:42:24 hp-lap systemd-journald[511]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/9bff4464ff444291ad1577b104dbcf39 is 62.805ms for 1059 entries.

Thus, nothing is logged for when the actual problem occurs.

Is it possible to force the log being flushed for every single line?